# How to dump remote database without using mysqlDump

Tags: ssh, backup, remote, mysql

I have a similar problem from this question [How to dump remote database without mysqldump?](https://serverfault.com/questions/134007/how-to-dump-remote-database-without-mysqldump)

How ever when I run

```
 ssh -f L 3306:localhost:3306 user@remoteserver -N
```

I am receive the following error

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 3306
Could not result local forwarding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely already running a local MySQL server that's using port 3306.

You can just change the local port for the tunneling like so:

```
  ssh -f -L 33306:localhost:3306 user@remoteserver -N
```

but of course you must point your local tools to port 33306 then.

Comment: so the next line of could should be `mysqldump -P 33306 -h localhost -u dbuser db` ?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: I get an error 'msqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect`

Comment: Try mysqldump -P 33306 -h 127.0.0.1 -u dbuser db to avoid a connection via a local socket.